# resetting video mode in masm

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I have this function where it draws colored boxes. The video mode needs to be set before drawing the boxes. The problem is, I couldn't reset the video mode back to the original mode. How could I do this?

Here is the code to draw the colored boxes:

```
mov ah, 00h ; set video mode
mov al, 13h ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
int 10h     ; set mode
mov ah, 0Ch ; change color for a single pixel
mov al, 1   ; color
mov bh, 0   ; page number
mov cx, 0   ; x
mov dx, 0   ; y
blue: int 10h   ; execute change
inc cx      ; increment x
cmp cx, 320 ; compare if x is 320
jne blue    ; if not, go to blue
mov cx, 0   ; reset x to 0
inc dx      ; increment y
cmp dx, 200 ; compare if y is 200
jne blue    ; if not, go to blue
...
...
;MOV AH, 08H
;INT 21H
;JMP start
;reset video mode
```

Comment: You could use int 10h/ah=0fh to get the original video mode and then using int 10h/ah=0h to set it back after. If you just want to go back to 80x25 16-color text mode you can use into 10h/ah=0h with a video mode of 3.

Comment: I tried the video mode of 3, but after setting it I couldn't type anything

Comment: Maybe you need to set the cursor position?

Comment: Nice to see a _commented_ code (even if a little too much for `inc` and `cmp` lines :p )

Comment: I do hope you did not try resetting the video mode right after this `JMP` instruction. (`;JMP start` `;reset video mode`)